# reduction of stream of object does not work for me

Tags: dictionary, jq, reduce

I wrote several reductions, where I had array to begin with. But if I try to read raw data and transform each line into object, I don't have much luck reducing them together

```
echo -e "1\n2\n\n\n3\n4\n5" | jq --raw-input '. | select (. != "") | {(.):123} | reduce . as $i ({}; . + $i)'
```

the reduction does nothing. Why? How to correct the reduction to produce single object having keys 1,2,3,4,5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the initial `.|` is unnecessary.

Second, since your input is a stream, you will either need to use the -s option, or better, use the -n option with `inputs`.

So you could go with:

```
echo -e "1\n2\n\n\n3\n4\n5" | 
  jq -nR 'reduce (inputs|select(. != "")) as $i ({}; . + {($i): 123})'
```

though maybe `{($i): null}` might be more appropriate.

Comment: thanks a lot. I forgot about -n and was wondering why is `inputs` stealing my first entry (I know why now) and thus came to conclusion that `inputs` is incorrect way (which is not). Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. To convert from multiple results to a single object, you can run another `jq` in slurp mode:

```sh
echo -e "1\n2\n\n\n3\n4\n5" \
| jq --raw-input 'select (. != "") | {(.):123}' \
| jq --slurp 'reduce .[] as $o ({}; . + $o)'
```

Comment: Two invocations is a bit extravagant, as indeed is --slurp, but if you were going down that rabbit hole, the second invocation could simply be: `jq -s add`